# SSRS Excel Export Runtime Error On Small Report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I keep having a specific report fail to export to Excel only.  I can export to CSV, MHTML, XML, TIFF, Word, and PDF with no issue.  The report is an extremely simple report with 2 matrices.  The only thing that I can think of that might be causing the issue is how I have the column groups stacked to get the report setup in rows with the headers on the left instead of columns with the headers on the top.  Are there any known issues with exporting to Excel in a setup like this?  Using SQL Server 2012 and Report Builder 3.0.  I can post anything else on there that might help explain what is going on.

I have tried dumping memory on the SQL server, increasing timeout limit, restarting server, saving and running report on another server, and numerous other "quick fixes" that have worked for other errors in the past.

Stack Trace Error below:

[ReportServerException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError)]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerUrlRequest(AbortState abortState, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension) +1018
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.Render(AbortState abortState, String reportPath, String executionId, String historyId, String format, XmlNodeList deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, Stream reportStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension) +1121
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.InternalRender(Boolean isAbortable, String format, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, Stream reportStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension) +425
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerModeSession.RenderReport(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection additionalParams, Boolean cacheSecondaryStreamsForHtml, String& mimeType, String& fileExtension) +209
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response) +219
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +221
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +586
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +177

Answer (score 0):

My data row did not have a title and as soon as I put just 1 character in there everything started working.